# How to fix this error encountered in generating a benchmark in Hyperledger Caliper? node:events:491 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^

Tags: generator, benchmarking, caliper, hyperledger-caliper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev89c.png)

I followed everything on this documentation https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.3.2/benchmark-generator/ but error "node:events:491 throw er;" is showing.

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: Expected `cwd` to be of type `string` but received type `undefined`
    at module.exports.sync (/home/jolly/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:60:9)
    at globDirs (/home/jolly/node_modules/globby/index.js:58:9)
    at getPattern (/home/jolly/node_modules/globby/index.js:61:64)
    at /home/jolly/node_modules/globby/index.js:107:19
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (/home/jolly/node_modules/globby/index.js:106:26)
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (/home/jolly/node_modules/mem-fs-    editor/lib/actions/copy.js:24:26)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as copyTpl] (/home/jolly/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy-tpl.js:29:8)
    at module.exports._workloadWrite (/home/jolly/node_modules/@hyperledger/generator-caliper/generators/benchmark/index.js:196:17)
    at module.exports.writing (/home/jolly/node_modules/@hyperledger/generator-caliper/generators/benchmark/index.js:255:14)
Emitted 'error' event on  instance at:
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/jolly/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:433:22)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)`
```

Comment: caliper v0.3.2 is very old, try again with calper v0.5.0 which is the latest version

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the reply. Yes, I tried the v.0.5.0. Everything's okay. thank you